# Are these class properties redundant?

Tags: php, class, properties

Here's the class I am working on. After uploading a file using a form, it POSTS to this php file which contains this class:

```
class Parse
{
    public $file;

    public function __construct()
    {
        echo 'The class was initiated!<br />';
    }

    public function setFile($file) 
    {
        if (sizeof($file) == 1)
        {
            $this->file = $file;
        }
    }

    public function getFileName()
    {
        return $this->file['uploadedfile']['name'];
    }

    public function getFileTempName()
    {
        return $this->file['uploadedfile']['tmp_name'];
    }

    public function getFileSize()
    {
        return $this->file['uploadedfile']['size'];
    }
}
```

Should I directly reference $obj->file['uploadedfile']['property'] like how I created the Getters, or should I create a bunch of public class properties like `public $filename` and store the values from the $_FILES variable into individual class properties?

Which is best-practice?

**EDITED WITH ANSWER**

This code works perfectly:

```
<?php

    class Parser
    {
        public $file;

        public function __construct()
        {
            echo 'The class was initiated!<br />';
        }

        public function setFile($file) 
        {
            if ($_POST) {
                if ($file['uploadedfile']['size'] > 0) {
                    $this->file = $file;
                } else {
                    echo "File not uploaded!<br />";
                }
            } else {
                echo "The form was not submitted!<br />";
            }
        }
    }

    ################
    # test area
    ################



    $obj = new LoLParser;
    $obj->setFile($_FILES);

    ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given that `$_FILES` is a superglobal, available in all scopes, <strike>you don't really gain anything</strike> there are some particular small gains by storing it as a class property.  There may be some benefit to holding it as a property for readability inside the class. As pointed out in comments, it also provides a path to mocking data for unit testing.

However, creating getter methods for `$_FILES` seems to add needless complexity and confusion in my opinion. Getters are useful to expose private or protected properties outside the class, but serve little purpose when accessing a superglobal, since you cannot protect the contents of a superglobal anyway.

Comment: By wrapping the behaviour in a class, you do gain two potential (related) benefits: this is now injectable and mockable.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth I'll agree with mockable, but still don't see much purpose to injecting a superglobal.

Comment: Well, it eliminates the dependency from whatever was previously directly accessing the superglobal.

Comment: Awesome, thank you for the insightful answer. Is this an acceptable way to tell if a file was uploaded?: `if ($_POST) {
   if ($file['uploadedfile']['name'] != "") {
    $this->file = $file;
   }
   else {
    echo "No file uploaded!<br />";
   } 
  }
  else {
   echo "NO POST!<br />";
  }`  I've noticed that $_FILES never returns empty even if you don't Browse to a file before submitting the form. Is this the proper way to check? This provides correct results, just not sure if best-practice :)

Comment: @pr0tocol I would probably just use `!empty($file['uploadedfile']['name'])` or `$_FILES['uploadedfile']['size'] > 0`

Comment: Oh, yea checking the file size would work great, Michael! Thank you.

Comment: @Michael abstracting PHP's superglobals is useful for PHP app servers (webservers written in PHP).

Comment: I should add that while checking the filesize worked perfectly, it still needs to be put inside an if-statement checking for $_POST, as neglecting to do so will result in an undefined index for $_FILES if accessing the script directly. Everything is working perfectly when put inside this if ($_POST) though